# Добавление и удаление из массива JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

У меня есть список

```
<ul>
<li><input type="ckeckbox" data-brand="audi"></li>
<li><input type="ckeckbox" data-brand="mersedes"></li>
<li><input type="ckeckbox" data-brand="bmw"></li>
</ul>
```

Есть переменная МАССИВ

```
let brandArrField = [];
```

Я хочу сделать так чтоб при клике на чебокс если установлена галочка добавлялась информация в массив из атрибута data-brand этого чебокса

Но при снятии галочки убиралась эта информация

Пытаюсь сделать что то типо такого

```
$('.custom-checkbox').click( function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('checked')
    } else {
        $(this).parents('li').removeClass('checked')
    }
    $(this).parents('ol').find('li.checked').each( function () {
        brandArrField = brandArrField + '"' + $(this).find('.custom-checkbox').attr('data-brand') + '",'
    })
    console.log(brandArrField)
})
```

Но при снятии галочки он просто плюсует значение к тому что было, возможно JS не успевает обработать информацию DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так хотели?

```js
let brandArrField = [];

$('.custom-checkbox').click( function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('checked')
    } else {
        $(this).parents('li').removeClass('checked')
    }
    brandArrField = [];
    $(this).parents('ul').find('li.checked').each( function () {
        brandArrField.push($(this).find('.custom-checkbox').attr('data-brand'));
    })
    console.log(brandArrField)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-brand="audi">audi</li>
<li><input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-brand="mersedes">mersedes</li>
<li><input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-brand="bmw">bmw</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Скорее всего да, но вот тут на stackoverflow работает в консоле а у меня консоль лог пишет пустой массив, сейчас подумаю с чем это может быть связано

Comment: Всеравно не понятно, пытаюсь добавить этот код в консоле, но картина та-же, в чем может быть причина

Comment: Теперь получилось, просто у вас в коде был UL а у меня Ol спасибо вам огромное